# Why am I getting just one value output from database?

Tags: php, foreach, symfony

I have an foreach loop in my php code. So i have some documents of some users, the user table and the document table are joined by user_id column in the document table. In the foreach loop i made an if statement, so if users id is equals user_id from the document table i need to output the title of the document, i have more documents of user id 1 but im getting just the first value of document title. Is my foreach loop wrong or im doing something else wrong?

```
 foreach($documents as $document) 
    {
        $user_id = $document['user_id'];
        $title = $document['title'];

        if($user_id == $id)
        {
            return new JsonResponse($title);
        }            
    }
```

So the $user_id is the value from the document table and the $id is the id value of a user.

[Here im getting just one value output and i have two documents for user with id 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxMAp.png)

Comment: `return` interrupts the script execution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `return` is interrupting the script execution at that point.

If you want to return all titles, then do

```
$titles = array();

foreach($documents as $document) 
{
    $user_id = $document['user_id'];
    $title = $document['title'];

    if($user_id == $id)
    {
        $titles[] = $title;
    }            
}

return new JsonResponse($titles);
```

Comment: thank you for saving my time to write this piece of code. I was going to write it exactly . :)